# Vapour-liquid equilibrium of solution

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a bottle with a mix of propane and butane. The mix is partially liquid and partially vapour at room temperature. What's the pressure of it? I can get the vapour pressure of both gases separately but what happen when I mix them? Suppose the liquid is 20% propane and 80% butane.
--Edit--
And what would be the mixture proportions of the vapour?

Comment: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/propane-butane-mix-d_1043.html gives you some idea of the vapour pressures which you can interpolate for you percentages.

Comment: Thanks. It answers my question as I phrased it. But I still don't get a full understanding of what is going on. What is the proportion of the mix in the vapour portion? Is it 20% 80% or some other?

Comment: If the liquids and gases are relatively non-interacting, than they can be considered ideal. You can then work out from the pure vapor pressures what the ratio in the gas phase will be.

Comment: How so? The pressure of the mix is intermidiate between both vapor pressures. I still don't get it.

Comment: Are you familiar with Raoult's Law?  If not, Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Raoult's Law, the partial pressure of each component in the vapor is equal to the equilibrium vapor pressure of the pure component at the same temperature as the liquid times the mole fraction of the component in the liquid.  This law applies to a nearly ideal mixture like propane and butane.

Comment: I agree with Chester Miller.  For more info, look at bubble point temperature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_point and dew point temperature http://www.mycheme.com/calculating-bubble-dew-points-for-ideal-mixtures/ for ideal mixtures.